# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators in web3js

Tags: web3js, javascript, web3js-v1.x

Below is my code snippet. I wish to wait for the transaction hash value so that I can return my Javascript function with the hash value.

But I get the error "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators" in Firefox console. I'm using web3js 1.0 at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js'

```
web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey).then(signed => {
  const tran = await web3.eth
    .sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
    .on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber, receipt) => {
      console.log('=> confirmation: ' + confirmationNumber);
    })
    .on('transactionHash', hash => {
      console.log('=> hash');
      console.log(hash);
      //console.log("HASH: ", hash);
      transHash = hash;
    })
    .on('receipt', receipt => {
      console.log('=> reciept');
      console.log(receipt);
    })
    .on('error', console.error);
});
```

Comment: you need to wrap that in a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
signed => {
```

To this:

```
function(signed) {
```

And then to this:

```
async function(signed) {
```

The middle phase is just an intermediate step in order clarify the syntax for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
async (signed) => {
```

if you want to use shorthand notation.